# Nested Module namespacing? Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, dynamic, module, namespaces

Given the following code structure...

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class A
    end
  end
  class B
    def initialize(stuff)
    ...
    end
  end
end
```

How could I call B's `.new` method from within class A ?

And, is there a way to do it dynamically, if perhaps I had a string that was the class name I wanted to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class A
    end
  end
  class B
    def initialize(stuff)
      puts "I like #{stuff}"
    end
  end
end
```

From anywhere you could invoke:

```
include Foo
klass = "B"
Module.const_get(klass).send(:new, "cats")
  #=> "I like cats"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call it statically:

```
module Foo
  class B
    def initialize(stuff)
    end
  end
  module Bar
    class A
      puts Foo::B.new(1)
    end
  end
end
```

To call it dinamically, check @CarySwoveland answer. You will need to use the methods const_get and send.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have it backward?  Asker wants to call `B.new(...)` from `A`, where the class name `B` might be the value of a variable.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Not as far as I know, but I'm interested if there is a way. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks folks! Appreciate your help.